# Kopete to work with GTalk

Tags: linux, debian, kde, google-talk, kopete

How can I get Kopete to connect to gtalk? I entered my username as blah@gmail.com and the gmail password but it stays offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GTalk username and password is not enough, you also have to specify a separate server address. Google has [instructions for Kopete](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?answer=57557).

Comment: The link is down and no information is available anymore.

Comment: Ah damn, should've repeated the instructions here. Then again: I think GMail has (or wants to) stop offering XMPP and also Kopete has probably been rewritten a couple of times since 2009 though so... Probably wouldn't have helped anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the Jabber account with the [correct settings](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/kopete_kde_instant_messenger?page=0%2C1) ?